# Can an injective smooth map from a smooth manifold into another smooth manifold have a discontinuous inverse?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I think the answer is yes. See the example below: we consider the open interval $(-1,\infty)$ as an open submanifold of the smooth manifold $(i,\mathbb{R})$ with $i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},i(x)=x$ being the chart. Similarly, $(i,\mathbb{R^2})$ is a smooth manifold with $i:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2,i(\textbf{x})=\textbf{x}$ being the chart.

Let $\varphi:(-1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\varphi(t)=\left(\frac{3t}{1+t^3},\frac{3t^2}{1+t^3} \right)$. The trace of $\varphi$ (with subspace topology) is the portion of the "folium of Descartes" lying in the first and second quadrants together with the origin. Observe that $\varphi$ is injective but near the origin, $\varphi^{-1}$ is not continuous (since $\varphi(0)=\textbf{0}$ but $\varphi(t)\rightarrow\textbf{0}$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$).

Hence, an injective smooth map between smooth manifolds can have a discontinuous inverse.

[[image: trace of <span class=]$\varphi$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfTb.png)

Comment: A self-intersecting curve isn't a manifold of dimension 1 because at the intersection point (your $0$) it isn't locally isomorphic to $(-1,1)$. If your curve isn't self-intersecting then your inverse map is smooth. It won't be a smooth function of the $\Bbb{R}^2$-coordinates  because with the $\Bbb{R}^2$ topology your curve is self-intersecting.

Comment: @reuns But for the inverse $\varphi^{-1}(\textbf{0})=0$, $\varphi^{-1}(\textbf{a})>10000$ for $\textbf{a}\in \varphi(-1,\infty)$ sufficiently close to $\textbf{0}$. So I don't think $\varphi^{-1}$ is even continous.

Comment: It is continuous and smooth in the topology of the non-self interscting curve. That topology is not the one coming from the $\Bbb{R}^2$ topology because it makes the curve self-intersecting

Comment: @reuns Sorry, could you explain what the definition of self-intersecting is? Is it that if every neighborhood around $\textbf{0}$ intersects the trace of $\varphi$, then $\varphi$ is self-intersecting?

Comment: If you take your example as a smooth map $f: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}^2$ then the restriction of the inverse to  the image of $f$ is obviously discontinuous. However, this cannot happen if the domain and the range are manifolds of the same dimension (and the map is injective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The preimage of any neighborhood of $0$ under $\phi^{-1}$, which is to say the image of $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ under $\phi$, will fail to be open in the subspace topology, since any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in the subspace topology contains a point $\phi(t)$ with $t>\epsilon$.

Note that not only is your map smooth and injective, it is even an [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)).

This is a good example of how injective immersions can fail to be [embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Embedded_submanifolds) when their domain isn't compact.

Another classic example is $\Bbb{R}\to T^2 = \Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{Z}^2$ given by $t\mapsto (t,\alpha t)$, where $\alpha$ is irrational. You can check that this is an injective immersion, but the open subsets of the image in the subspace topology have unbounded preimage, so the image of a bounded open subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is never open in the image.

See the image on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus) to get a sense of this last example.